# I want to convert rows 2 rows as 2 columns in sql 2000 without using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I want to convert rows 2 rows as 2 columns in sql 2000
without using pivot

eg:

```
A    B    C
---- ---- -------
78   68   3
```

I want the output as

```
Projects  Count
--------- ------- 
A         78
B         68  
C         3
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your example doesn't make sense to me - your input contains only 1 row?

Comment: @Frank - I would say OP wants to move the values from columns into the rows of another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you indeed want a pivot query:

```
select 'A' as Projects, A as my_count from mytab
union all
select 'B' as Projects, B as my_count from mytab
union all
select 'C' as Projects, C as my_count from mytab
```

(I've replaced count with my_count, since COUNT is a reserved word in SQL).

Comment: Possibly neater than my example, but does this parse as three table scans instead of one?

Comment: @Dems yes, this will result in 3 table scans, so your solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  pivot.field,
  CASE pivot.field
    WHEN 'A' THEN A
    WHEN 'B' THEN B
    WHEN 'C' THEN C
  END as value
FROM
  my_table
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 'A' AS field UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'C') AS pivot
```